# why do we build a dictionary of variables in tensorflow

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow

In an example code, I saw that people build dictionaries of variables(weights/biases) in tensorflow. I wonder what is the benefit of that, compared with defining variables separately

Diictionary style:

```
weights = { 
    'encoder_w1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], stddev= sd), name='encoder_w1'), 
    'encoder_w2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], stddev= sd), name='encoder_w2'), 
    'decoder_w1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_1], stddev= sd), name='decoder_w1'), 
    'decoder_w2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_input], stddev= sd), name='decoder_w2')
}
biases = { 
    'encoder_b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1], stddev= sd), name='encoder_b1'), 
    'encoder_b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2], stddev= sd), name='encoder_b2'), 
    'decoder_b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1], stddev= sd), name='decoder_b1'), 
    'decoder_b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input], stddev= sd), name='decoder_b2') 
}
```

Separate style:

```
encoder_w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], stddev= sd), name='encoder_w1')
encoder_w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], stddev= sd), name='encoder_w2')
decoder_w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], stddev= sd), name='decoder_w1')
#... (you get the idea) `
```

Thanks!

Comment: it's completely a matter of comfort, specifically to pass all of them together as an argument to a function for example is quite nice like that, but the results of that will be the same

Answer (score 0):

"Dictionary style" will make it easier to refer to a whole group at once (say, to pass to a function).

Comment: Is that achieved by doing, e.g.: 
`list(weights.values())` ?

Comment: will name_scope be able to do similar things compared with dictionary of variables?